# Toggle class of separate element and remove class

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this code:

```
<ul>        
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Menu item One</a>
    <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#" onclick=""><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick=""><span>Location</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Menu item Two</a>
    <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#" onclick=""><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick=""><span>Location</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to click '.plus' and the below '.submenu' to toggle a class.

And for that I have:

```
$('.plus').click( function() { 
    $(this).next().toggleClass("someClass");
});
```

Which works fine. What I need it to do is not only toggle the class off and on but also to remove the class if another '.plus' link is clicked.

So it should:

1. Toggle the class off and on if you keep clicking the same '.plus'
2. Remove the class from any other '.plus' link and add class to the clicked 'plus'
3. Also ideally the '+' text should change to '-' when clicked

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you need you can just call `removeClass()` on all other `.submenu` elements. To change the `+` to a `-` you can use the `text()` method to toggle the value based on it's current setting. You can also remove the empty `onclick` attributes. Try this:

```js
$('.plus').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $target = $(this).text(function(i, t) {
    return t == '+' ? '-' : '+';
  }).next().toggleClass("someClass");
  
  $('.submenu').not($target).removeClass('someClass');
  $('.plus').not(this).text('+');
});
```

```css
li li { display: none; }
li ul.someClass li { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item One</a>
    <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item Two</a>
    <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats it, perfect! Thanks